# File I/O confusion

Tags: c, file, io

I've just started with FILE I/O today, and I'm confused here. The while loop in the code below gives a weird output. It prints `i` starting from `i = 1`, and then `a[1] = ..` But outside the while loop, I've specified `i = 0`. Any reason for why `i` is incrementing to 1 after entering the while loop? The confusing thing though is that the final for loop, is printing `a[0] = 0` correctly!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 11

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i, a[N];
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "w");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",i);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    i = 0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        printf("i = %d ",i);
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i]);
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT: Got the above issue clarified, another confusion now. After reading the last number in the file, shouldn't the feof(fp) return a non-zero value and thus terminate the while loop? Why is it executing the loop one extra time?**

Comment: [For me, it doesn't, actually](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4960980/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-21%20at%206.22.56%20PM.png). Numbers begin from 0.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks on ubuntu 12.10(Yeah I'm using GCC) Its beginning from 0, uptill N = 9, but after that its giving me that problem!

Comment: Can you please show the output? Printscreen or copy paste it.

Comment: @NishadDawkhar The IDE is irrelevant, what you probably wanted to tell us is the compiler, which is most likely GCC. But ***there should not be a compiler bug...***

Comment: may be you are pasting a wrong code or wrong error.

Comment: Try compiling it again. Maybe you didn't compile after making changes.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://i48.tinypic.com/almblt.png

Comment: Your code is right. I ran this and I got numbers starting from 0.

Comment: Did you check my screenshot? Why am I getting the output like that?

Comment: An answer for the bonus question: Using `while(!feof(fp))` is always wrong, as it tells you if the previous read already failed, not if the next read will work. Check the return value of `fscanf` instead, to see if it found anything in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal cuts off the first line of the output because it's too long.

Comment: Oh okay, but I'm not able to get it printed even when I expand the size of the terminal!

Comment: @Nishad That's the fault of the vendor of your terminal. What if you redirect the output of your program into a file, and then open that file using Gedit?

Comment: @Nishad Scroll up in the terminal, don't resize it after the fact. Or, open a normal terminal and run the program directly from in there.

Comment: @Nishad - or add a `getchar()` or some "pause" type mechanism after each line/block to see the data as it's being printed out without it scrolling off the screen.

Comment: Yeah, its copying the output to a file correctly.. thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Nishad You can compensate me for the facepalm by accepting my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Mike - yeah, that works too! Edited the question a bit btw, need help!